# Is there any example and usage of url.QueryEscape ? for golang

Tags: go

How to understand and use `url.QueryEscape`, in Go language?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To understand the usage of `url.QueryEscape`, you first need to understand what a [url query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is.

A query string is a part of URL that contains data that can be passed to web applications. This data needs to be encoded, and this encoding is done using `url.QueryEscape`. It performs what is also commonly called [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding).

**Example**

Let's say we have webpage:

```
http://mywebpage.com/thumbify
```

And we want to pass an image url, `http://images.com/cat.png`, to this web application. Then this url needs look something like this:

```
http://mywebpage.com/thumbify?image=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.com%2Fcat.png
```

In Go code, it would look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    webpage := "http://mywebpage.com/thumbify"
    image := "http://images.com/cat.png"
    fmt.Println( webpage + "?image=" + url.QueryEscape(image))
}
```

Comment: why should we do like this, rather than directly use the image url?

Comment: It is part of the standard and it is required. Some characters are not allowed in urls (like space), and some characters have special meanings in the url (like =, # or &). Without encoding we cannot say if & is part of the data or if it is a delimiter.