# library/package in go that handles string encoding?

Tags: go

Are there any similar libraries/packages in go that emulate what `vis(3)` and `unvis(3)` do for BSD systems? I'm trying to do something that requires   representation of strings that contain special characters like whitespace and such.

Comment: do [strconv.Quote](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Quote) or QuoteToASCII do what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

No, Not exactly, but if you are looking for URL encoding, You can do all the URL encoding you want with the `net/url` package:
see:  [Encode / decode URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820280/encode-decode-urls)
and:  [Is there any example and usage of url.QueryEscape ? for golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921619/is-there-any-example-and-usage-of-url-queryescape-for-golang)

sample code:

```
fmt.Println(url.QueryEscape("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go test\r \r\n"))
```

output:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fgo+test%0D+%0D%0A
```

---

or write your own:

in Go string is `UTF-8` encoded, and is in effect a read-only slice of bytes:
you may get bytes like this:

```
str := "UTF-8"
bytes := []byte(str)    //   string to slice
fmt.Println(str, bytes) // UTF8 [85 84 70 45 56]
```

or convert bytes to string like this:

```
s := string([]byte{85, 84, 70, 45, 56, 32, 0xc2, 0xb5}) // slice to string
fmt.Println(s)                                          // UTF-8 µ
```

0xC2 0xB5  is UTF-8 (hex) for Character 'MICRO SIGN' (U+00B5) see: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/index.htm

also you may get bytes like this:

```
for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%d: %d, ", i, s[i])
    //0: 85, 1: 84, 2: 70, 3: 45, 4: 56, 5: 32, 6: 194, 7: 181,
}
```

or in compact Hex format:

```
fmt.Printf("% x\n", s) // 55 54 46 2d 38 20 c2 b5
```

and get runes (Unicode codepoints) like this:

```
for i, v := range s {
    fmt.Printf("%d: %v, ", i, v)
    //0: 85, 1: 84, 2: 70, 3: 45, 4: 56, 5: 32, 6: 181, 
}
```

see: [What is a rune?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310700/what-is-a-rune)

and convert rune to string:

```
r := rune(181)
fmt.Printf("%#U\n", r) // U+00B5 'µ'
st := "this is UTF-8: " + string(r)
fmt.Println(st) // this is UTF-8: µ
```

convert slice of runes to string:

```
rs := []rune{181, 181, 181, 181}
sr := string(rs)
fmt.Println(sr) // µµµµ
```

convert string to slice of runes:

```
br := []rune(sr)
fmt.Println(br) //[181 181 181 181]
```

The %q (quoted) verb will escape any non-printable byte sequences in a string so the output is unambiguous:

```
fmt.Printf("%+q \n", "Hello, 世界") // "Hello, \u4e16\u754c"
```

`unicode.IsSpace` reports whether the rune is a space character as defined by Unicode's White Space property; in the Latin-1 space this is

'\t', '\n', '\v', '\f', '\r', ' ', U+0085 (NEL), U+00A0 (NBSP). 
sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    s := "\u4e16\u754c \u0020\r\n  世界"
    for _, r := range s {
        if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\\u%04x", r))
        } else {
            buf.WriteString(string(r))
        }
    }
    st := buf.String()
    fmt.Println(st)
}
```

output:

```
世界\u0020\u0020\u000d\u000a\u0020\u0020世界
```

You can find more functions in the `unicode/utf8`, `unicode`, `strconv` and `strings` packages:
https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/
https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/
https://golang.org/pkg/strings/
https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/

https://blog.golang.org/strings